# initVector for stream processing using AES

Tags: encryption, io, stream

Is it safe to use the same initVector to write using CipherOutputStream to encrypt various parts of a file that will eventually be written to disk? I'll use the same key, but would probably like to use a different iv every time I call cos.write(). Now if this is to be done, I need to secure randomly generate a new iv every time. Then during decryption, how do I pass these init vectors to the decrypting cipher. Can the iv be embedded in the file content and read back in a deterministic way? I can fix the length of the iv if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **initialization vector** (IV) is used to start of the chaining mode. After that the chaining mode initialized by this IV is in effect until you **close the cipher stream**.

If you **need to** switch IV mid stream, you would need to **finish off** the ongoing encryption stream including applying any applicable padding. This opens up for the need for a scheme for identifying when one "encryption stream" ends, and a new start.

Unless you need some kind of **random access**, or you have **data in clear mixed with encrypted data**, you would normally just encrypt all the data in one stream with one unique IV.

As for the **IV**, you can just pre-pend it to your file before the encrypted data. This allows you to read it just before you instantiate your Cipher Stream.

Comment: Great, Thanks! Is there someplace I can read about the chaining you mentioned.

Comment: [Wiki have a great article on this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation)

Comment: Also, I was able to write the iv into the bytestream itself during encryption, so I read back so many bytes during decryption.